# Change name in ItemAdding event receiver or create a new Item

Tags: event-receivers, rename

I have several custom folder types such as Year Folder or Quarter Folder. When the user creates a folder of this type he enters the name and selects an item from a dropdown (year etc.). 90% of the time the name is identical to the value of the dropdown so I am going to use JavaScipt to populate the Name feild in the new item form with a token. If the user doesn't change the token, I will use an ItemAdding event receiver to replace the token value with the value from the dropdown.

However, I have run into a problem. I can't actually chnage the "Name" feild.

```
    properties.AfterProperties["Name"];
```

doesn't exist. The internal name of "name" is FileLeafRef but if try to access it, I get an error that it is read only.

So is it possible to change the "Name" propertie in ItemAdding event receiver?

I have also attempted to cancel the creation of the item in ItemAdding event receiver and create my own new item. The code is below

```
     public void createItem(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {

       try
       {


           SPList list = properties.List;
           SPWeb web = properties.Web;
           string url = properties.AfterUrl;
           SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(url);

           SPContentType type = list.ContentTypes[properties.AfterProperties["ContentType"].ToString()];

           if (checkIfFolder(type)) // checks if current item is a folder
           {

               string name = replaceTokens(properties); // returns the new name that will be used


               SPItem newItem = list.Items.Add(url, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, name);

               foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in properties.AfterProperties)
               {
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entry.Key.ToString() + " " + entry.Value.ToString());
                   if (entry.Key.ToString() != "FileSystemObjectType")
                   {
                       newItem[entry.Key.ToString()] = entry.Value.ToString();
                   }
               }

               this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
               newItem.Update();
               this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
           }
       }
       catch (SPException spEx) 
       {
           // file already exists? 
           //if (spEx.ErrorCode == -2130575257) 
           //    return false;  
           //else
           //    throw spEx;  
       }  
   }
```

This code executes and no errors are generated. However, no new item is created either. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to rather execute your code in the ItemAdded. Do not try to re-create another item inside, you just need to execute the code at the appropiate moment.

Make sure you read this article to understand when the AfterProperties has values populated as it is different from List to Library and for each Event http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/

In addition, you would also want to consider how the Event is executing Syncronous/Asyncronous (this is set in the Feature as part of the event receiver declarations).

```
<Receiver>
  <Name>MoviesEventListItemAdded</Name>
  <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
  <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
  <Class>Movies.MoviesEventList.MoviesEventList</Class>
  <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
  <Synchronization>Asynchronous</Synchronization>
</Receiver>
```

For example on how to update properties in the ItemAdded http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough2/